# Chrome alarms don't work with variables?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I am making a chrome extension for notifications, using the notifications API and alarms API. I have tested both and they work, but when I try to set the name of the alarm and it's time from a user input, suddenly it doesn't work at all. 
 Code:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    var $request = $('#request');
    var r = $request.val().split(' in '),
            name = r[0],
            amount = r[1];

    console.log('name:' + name + ', amount: ' + amount); // WORKS

    /*
     * WORKS *
    chrome.alarms.create('alarm_test', {
        delayInMinutes: 1
    });
    */

    /* DOESN'T WORK */
    chrome.alarms.create(name, {
       delayInMinutes: amount
    });

    console.log('alarm set.');

    $request.val('');
    return false;
});
```

This is pretty weird. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What does `chrome.alarms.getAll` shows you?

Comment: You should either answer your own question or delete it.

Comment: Thanks I just needed to wait before I could submit an answer... And for some reason now I have to wait before I can approve my answer.

Comment: @Gofilord This is a SO mechanism to allow for _better_ answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, all I had to do was the parse `amount` using `parseFloat()` method. It now works.